# Using feature test macros with GCC-7

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

I'm trying to use a [feature test macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) with GCC 7.3.  Specifically, I'm testing for guaranteed copy elision with the `__cpp_guaranteed_copy_elision` macro.

I'm using GCC 7.3 with the `-std=c++17` flag.   Here, I actually *write code* that *definitely* requires guaranteed copy elision (I return an `std::atomic<int>` by value).  The code works and compiles fine.  Yet my feature test macro test always fails for `__cpp_guaranteed_copy_elision`.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> F() { return std::atomic<int>{}; }

int main()
{
#if __cpp_guaranteed_copy_elision
        std::cout << "Have guaranteed copy elision" << std::endl;
#else
        std::cout << "Don't have it" << std::endl;
#endif

        std::atomic<int> a = F();
}
```

I compile this with:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++17
```

And it always outputs:

```
Don't have it
```

I also tried:

```
#if defined(__cpp_guaranteed_copy_elision)
```

And it still reports negative.  So does GCC 7.3 simply not support this macro?  Or am I using feature test macros incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So does GCC 7.3 simply not support this macro?

It doesn't. gcc didn't add this particular feature test macro until 8.3 and 9.1. This despite seeming to support guaranteed copy elision since 7.1, which is unfortunate. Not much you can do about it now.

> Or am I using feature test macros incorrectly?

Checking for just `__cpp_guaranteed_copy_elision` being defined is correct, yes (`#ifdef x` or `#if defined(x)` are fine).

Although the point of the macros is to be able to conditionally use a feature - and here your code requires it anyway... so I'm not sure what you would want to do in the case where the feature is not available.